# Inverse functions and asymptotic equivalence 2

Tags: asymptotics, inverse-function

Let $f$ and $h_1$ be monotone functions. Let $g$ be the inverse function of $f$ and $h_2$ the inverse function of $h_1$. Furthermore we know that $f\sim h_1$. If the last statement holds - under what conditions can we infer $g\sim h_2$?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by $\sim$?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it would be obvious from the title. $f(x)\sim g(x)\: (x \rightarrow\infty) := \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)/g(x)$.

Comment: You mean that the limit must be equal to 1 right?

Comment: Yes I forgot the $1$.

Comment: How about this? $f/h_1$ has limit equal to one for $x\to\infty$, and $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ have limits because they are the inverse of monotone functions. Then the limit of $f^{-1}/h_1^{-1}$ should exist and be equal to the inverse of 1, which is one.